# Move a ceiling or floor pattern using the Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I want to be able to adjust the pattern inside a particular ceiling using the Revit API.  Below are the screenshots of the before and after:

[image: Prepare move][image: After Move]

I've tried using the [Revit Lookup tool](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup) to find out what properties have changed after manually moving the lines using the user interface but I have been unable to determine which properties are changing.  In addition to looking at the `Ceiling` instance I've also used the [temporary delete transaction](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/11/access-to-sketch-and-sketch-plane.html) to discover that their is a `Sketch`, a `SketchPlane`, and multiple `ModelLine` associated with the `Ceiling` instance.  Looking into these objects I find no changes either.  What am I missing?

Comment: Basically what Jeremy has said. First of all there is no API for this particular behavior that you want. Secondly, what you found by deleting the object, that there are model lines associated with it, is exactly what you can use to make a workaround for this type of workflow. Delete the ceiling, catch model lines, store their Ids, roll back your transaction to undo delete, apply MoveElement to the model line that you got stored. That's the only way that I can think of this working.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I am dealing with a similar situation and my research took me to the same things you tried and wasn't successful yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for the `MoveElement( Document, ElementId, XYZ)` method, it appears what you're missing might be the `Location` property of your elements.

See [Autodesk Docs](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Revit-API/files/GUID-CD3B9A83-8DBC-418E-8099-D655AB3DA010-htm.html) for more info.

And also [Revit API Docs](http://www.revitapidocs.com/).

Comment: I'm aware of the `ElementTransformUtils` function `MoveElement`.  The problem is which element do I move?

Comment: If you have access to the ModelLine.Location property, can you calculate which of those is your desired target?  (I'm making assumptions here having never used the library before.)

Comment: Just found http://www.revitapidocs.com/ which has a VERY nice docs for the api you're using.  Well worth looking into that.  There's a `UniqueId` property you could use to identify the correct one perhaps.

Comment: The `ModelLine` returned from the temporary delete just moves the whole ceiling and not the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The description of how to [Align the Surface Pattern on a Model Element](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Revit-Customize/files/GUID-C2FC3823-56EB-4F21-A3EC-56CD15250AB0-htm.html) manually through the user interface describes how to access the 'surface pattern line' which controls the pattern position. You will probably need to identify this specific line and apply `MoveElement` to that.

Comment: How can I identify this line?  I've tried moving the `ModelLine` elements that come from doing a temporary delete but that just moves the whole ceiling instead of just the pattern.  The only other element id that comes out of a temporary delete is the `Sketch` and `SketchPlane`.